# How to revert Mocking

Tags: python, mocking, pytest, python-unittest

I almost went mad by the time I figured out why my test file runs smoothly but breaks if  tests are run together for the whole package with `pytest`.

I have a parent class and a child class. The child calls the parent's init like:

```py
class Child(Parent):
    __init__(...,**kwargs):
        ...
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
```

I wanted to define this behavior with a tiny test.

```py
from unittest.mock import Mock

def test_init_calls_parent_init():
    Parent.__init__ = Mock()
    
    Child()

    assert Parent.__init__.called
```

The problem is `Parent.__init__` **remained persistently a mock** for all the following tests in other files.

I had the notion that putting it into a function scope makes it only a temporary change. Of course since those tests broke, they implicitly define the need for the parent init but I wanted to make sure with one explicit test as well.

Should I create some `pytest` setup/teardown or what is the accepted way to prevent this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you performed `Parent.__init__ = Mock()`, you basically redefined the `__init__` of the module itself, which then reflected on the succeeding tests.

Instead of manually changing the implementation of `Parent.__init__` to `Mock`, my suggestion is to just use instead the patching functionality already available in [unittest](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#patch) and [pytest-mock](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-mock/).

- We can also use [monkeypatch](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/monkeypatch.html) as suggested by @MattSom (see comments section)

**src.py**

```
class Parent:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        print("Parent __init__ called")

class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        print("Child __init__ called")
```

### Without the correction:

```
from unittest.mock import Mock, patch

from src import Child, Parent


def test_init_calls_real_parent_init():
    Child()


def test_init_calls_updated_parent_init():
    Parent.__init__ = Mock()

    Child()

    assert Parent.__init__.called


def test_init_calls_real_parent_init_2():
    Child()
```

Output:

```
$ pytest -q test_src.py -rP
...                                                                                                                                                                                                 [100%]
================================================================================================= PASSES ==================================================================================================
____________________________________________________________________________________ test_init_calls_real_parent_init _____________________________________________________________________________________
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ Captured stdout call -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Parent __init__ called
Child __init__ called
___________________________________________________________________________________ test_init_calls_updated_parent_init ___________________________________________________________________________________
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ Captured stdout call -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Child __init__ called
___________________________________________________________________________________ test_init_calls_real_parent_init_2 ____________________________________________________________________________________
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ Captured stdout call -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Child __init__ called
3 passed in 0.01s
```

Findings:

The 1st test called the real `Parent.__init__`. The 2nd test called the mock. During the 3rd test however, it also unexpectedly called the mock made in the 2nd test.

### With correction:

```
from unittest.mock import Mock, patch

from src import Child, Parent


def test_init_calls_real_parent_init():
    Child()


# Personally I wouldn't advise to do this. It just works :)
def test_init_calls_updated_parent_init():
    # Setup
    orig_parent_init = Parent.__init__  # Store original init

    # Real test
    Parent.__init__ = Mock()

    Child()

    assert Parent.__init__.called

    # Teardown
    Parent.__init__ = orig_parent_init  # Bring back the original init


@patch("src.Parent.__init__")  # Uses unittest
def test_init_calls_mocked_parent_init(mock_parent_init):
    Child()

    assert mock_parent_init.called


def test_init_calls_mocked_parent_init_2(mocker):  # Uses pytest-mock
    mock_parent_init = mocker.patch("src.Parent.__init__")

    Child()

    assert mock_parent_init.called


def test_init_calls_real_parent_init_2():
    Child()
```

Output:

```
$ pytest -q test_src_2.py -rP
.....                                                                                                                                                                                               [100%]
================================================================================================= PASSES ==================================================================================================
____________________________________________________________________________________ test_init_calls_real_parent_init _____________________________________________________________________________________
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ Captured stdout call -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Parent __init__ called
Child __init__ called
___________________________________________________________________________________ test_init_calls_updated_parent_init ___________________________________________________________________________________
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ Captured stdout call -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Child __init__ called
___________________________________________________________________________________ test_init_calls_mocked_parent_init ____________________________________________________________________________________
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ Captured stdout call -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Child __init__ called
__________________________________________________________________________________ test_init_calls_mocked_parent_init_2 ___________________________________________________________________________________
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ Captured stdout call -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Child __init__ called
___________________________________________________________________________________ test_init_calls_real_parent_init_2 ____________________________________________________________________________________
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ Captured stdout call -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Parent __init__ called
Child __init__ called
5 passed in 0.03s
```

Findings:

Here I used 2 solutions:

1. Either change back the original implementation of `Parent.__init__` after the manual reassignment to mock (see `test_init_calls_updated_parent_init`) (not advisable)
2. Or use the builtin patching abilities of unittest and pytest-mock (see `test_init_calls_mocked_parent_init` and `test_init_calls_mocked_parent_init_2`)

Now, both the first and the last test correctly calls the actual `Parent.__init__`, even after all the mocks made.

Comment: Thanl you for the elaborate answer including the anti-patterns as well! This is great because at first I've done with that as well (by creating an `origin_parent_init`). 
Eventually I've made a monkeypatch since pytest has that fixture. You could ad that option too I think:

```python
def test_init_calls_parent_init(monkeypatch):
    monkeypatch.setattr(ModificationRequest, "__init__", Mock())

    ProducerModificationRequest()

    assert ModificationRequest.__init__.called
```

Comment: Good suggestion :) I updated the answer with `monkeypatch` as an alternative. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try converting the parent into a [fixture, which defaults to having a "function" scope](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/fixture.html#fixture-scopes), which theoretically should teardown the fixture after each test.

Remember to [yield your fixture](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/fixture.html#yield-fixtures-recommended) and add any other necessary teardown instructions afterwards.

The reason your Parent does not deconstruct the mock is because parent classes/functions that aren't fixtures are treated like any other parent/child functions.

Comment: Hey Chris, thank you for the answer! One question: how can I ensure that this fixture will be called by the child?

Comment: On the page I linked is instructions for calling fixtures, specifically [here](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/fixture.html#requesting-fixtures) or [here](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/fixture.html#autouse-fixtures-fixtures-you-don-t-have-to-request)

Comment: I mean the child inherits from a parent class. It can't inherit from a fixture.